# getOrder() doesn't return Mage_Sales_Model_Order when debugging

Tags: magento-1.9, database, sales-order, custom-block, getmodel

I try to `var_dump($order)` but it gives me :

```
object(Varien_Object)#290 (7) { ["_data":protected]=> array(0) { } ["_hasDataChanges":protected]=> bool(false) ["_origData":protected]=> NULL ["_idFieldName":protected]=> NULL ["_isDeleted":protected]=> bool(false) ["_oldFieldsMap":protected]=> array(0) { } ["_syncFieldsMap":protected]=> array(0) { } }
```

My `class PaketId_Shipping_Block_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_Shipment_View_Shipping extends Mage_Core_Block_Template {`

```
protected $order;

public function getOrder() {
    if (is_null($this->order)) {
        if (Mage::registry('current_order')) {
            $order = Mage::registry('current_order');
        }
        elseif (Mage::registry('order')) {
            $order = Mage::registry('order');
        }
        else {
            $order = new Varien_Object();
        }
        $this->order = $order;
    }
    return $this->order;
}
```

My phtml file :

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('PaketId_Shipping');?>
<h1>Test custom block</h1>
<?php $order = $this->getOrder()?>
<?php var_dump($order);?>
<?php $shippings = Mage::getModel('paketid_shipping/result')->getCollection()->addOrderFilter($order) ?>
<?php echo "<pre>";?>
<?php var_dump($shippings);?>
<?php echo "</pre>" ;?>
```

My variable `$order` in phtml file somehow doesn't call the `$order` in block file, or I have been misunderstanding about this? Because, when i try to `var_dump($order)` in other phtml, it returns `object(Mage_Sales_Model_Order)#276...`

Comment: it gives me `array(0)`

Comment: it gives me `object(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote)#390 (21) { ["_eventPrefix":protected]=> string(11) "sales_quote" ["_eventObject":protected]=> string(5) "quote" ["_cacheTag":protected]=> string(5) "quote" ["_customer":protected]=> NULL ["_addresses":protected]=> NULL ["_items":protected]=> NULL ["_payments":protected]=> NULL [...]` what does this means?

Comment: how to determine if the result of `$order = Mage::getSingleton[...]` is my current order ?

Comment: it gives me `NULL` when changing into `getSingleton('sales/order')`

Comment: it gives me `object(Mage_Sales_Model_Order)#291 (29) {
  ["_eventPrefix":protected]=>
  string(11) "sales_order"
  ["_eventObject":protected]=>
  string(5) "order"` what does the `#291` means?

Comment: it gives me `array(0)` :(

Comment: why it has no order yet? im so confuse

Comment: same. returns `null`

Comment: I need to get `current_order` in order to run the `mage::getModel('paketid_shipping/result')->getCollection()` I want to retrieve records from another table which has `order_id` in it

Comment: if i haven't got the `$order`, i can't continue to the next query

Comment: still the same, returns `null`. Have you recognize anything wrong with my block file? or it has something to do with model file?

Comment: the current order should be called because I have declare it in `mage::registry('current_order')` or I am doing it wrong?